# Netlogo Mondrian Painting Generator

Tags: netlogo, mondrian

How can I create a mondrian painting generator in NetLogo?

my current progress is on how to generate the rectangles with borders themselves, not not how to order them so that they no not overlap.

Any hints/solutions/help in general would be appreciated.

Ciao

Comment: Please provide the code that isn't working, a description of what you want it to do, and a description of what it is doing instead.

Comment: Sorry, I already found an answer by thinking for like ~5 hours.